# Rails custom Validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm trying to write a custom validation in rails to check if the value I am entering is a duplicate in the database.

The values I need to check against is based off 4 different tables/models

I'm trying to write something like this for the validation:

```
class Locations::BranchBusinessGroup < Locations::Database

validate :url_duplicated

private
  def url_duplicated
    if self.location.url_prefix.valid?
      errors.add(:location, 'URL is take')
    else
      if self.custom_url.valid? && self.self.business_group.is_on_web #both in different models 
        errors.add(:location, 'URL is used in a custom URL')
      end 
    end 
 end
```

`url_prefix`, `url_suffix`, ':custom_url', `is_on_the_web`  are all fields that are being entered by the form.  the Logic is supposed to check whether  the `url_prefix` and `url_suffix` have been already entered if they haven't does it match ':custom_url' and `is_on_the_web`.

Obsessively this is not the right way of coding this and its super wrong.  Its just the idea of how i would want to check the validation. Any light shed on this will be great.

error i get is:

`undefined method`valid?' for "chantilly-va":String`

Comment: Edited. Would like to know how can I write such a custom validation.

Comment: What ORM are you using, ActiveRecord?  What is the parent `Locations::Database` class? Also, please clarify what the logic is that would make this record invalid.  It's very unclear from your example what `url_suffix`, `custom_url`, and `is_on_web` are supposed to represent.

Comment: Not sure why you are using `:` in front of attribute names. Can you explain why?

Comment: Its because I am not sure how the code should written so I know the syntax is wrong. Just had it up there as a concept.

Comment: You could transform the second block `else - if` into an `elsif` statement. Anyways, it seems you're asking without even trying your code.

Comment: See edited script with error message.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me exactly what `Location` and `BusinessGroup` are, but the general idea would be something like this:

```
def url_duplicated
  if self.class.where(url_prefix: url_prefix).where.not(id: id).exists?
    errors.add(:location, 'URL is taken')
  elsif self.class.where(custom_url: custom_url, is_on_web: true).where.not(id: id).exists?
    errors.add(:location, 'URL is used in a custom URL')
  end 
end
```

Essentially, you want to do a lookup to find if any record exists that matches these terms (and doesn't have the record's own `id`).  Note, the `where.not(...)` syntax which will only work starting with Rails 4.